# Best database structure to keep values that gets updated often

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, database-normalization

I currently am designing new system based on a legacy one, and am facing this problem regarding the database structure.

I have 4 tables which are SalesOrder and SalesOrderLine; DelivNote and DelivNoteLine. SalesOrderLine table consists of list of item that are ordered with its quantity and selling price. DelivNoteLine table will read data from SalesOrderLine table and create entries for the item that have been delivered. The delivery can be done partially, so i need to keep track of the delivered item and the outstanding item for each Sales Order.

For example, Sales Order X sold 4 qty of item A, then i make delivery note for 1 qty of item A, with a reference to Sales Order X. Where do i store the value of the 3 qty of the outstanding item.

Currently, the table structured like this

```
so_id, so_name, so_desc
    3     SO-X      XXX

soline_id, so_id, soline_quantity, sod_price, sod_outstanding_quantity 
        1      3                4      1.000                        3

dn_id, dn_name, so_id, dn_desc
    1     DN-A   SO-X      XXX

dnline_id, dn_id, dnline_quantity
        1      1                1
```

This can works, but i heard that its better to calculate the outstanding quantity based on sum of dnline_quantity. Any suggestion?